# MNIST pytorch dataset shape of images

Tags: python, pytorch, mnist

I am training a neural network with Pytorch, and I would like to understand more of Mnist dataset.
The dataloader looks like this:

```
batch_size = 128
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((28,28)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5), (0.5)),
])
train_dataset = datasets.MNIST('./data', transform=transform, download=True)
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

test_dataset = datasets.MNIST('./data', transform=transform, download=True, train=False)
test_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
```

However, when I train my own dataset there are problems loading the data. What I know is that the Mnist dataset for pytorch has the shape of (1,28,28) which are grayscaled images. I want to know how they are saved. Are they png, jpg, jpeg or npy files?

Comment: What the code does depends crucially on the `transform`, and you haven't told us what it is...

Comment: The data is just a big array of the pixel values, you can look at it by inspecting e.g. `train_dataset.dataset.data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MNIST dataset class is based on [this code](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/mnist.html#MNIST). If you would like to use your own dataset, you should write your custom dataset class to read your dataset based on its properties, like its image size, number of channels, labels, etc.

For instance something like this example:

```
class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, annotations_file, img_dir, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.img_labels = pd.read_csv(annotations_file)
        self.img_dir = img_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_labels)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 0]) 
       
        image = scipyIO.loadmat(img_path).get('rawData')
        image = image.astype(np.float64)
        h, w = image.shape
        image = torch.from_numpy(image).reshape(1, h, w)
        image = image.float()

        ua = self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 1]    # 1: ua value
        us = self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 2]    # 2: us value
        g = self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 3]     # 3: g value

        gt = torch.tensor([ua, us, g])
        
        gt = gt.float()

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        if self.target_transform:
            gt = self.target_transform(gt)

        return image, gt
```

(above example is based on [this repository](https://github.com/liangyuxuan1/phasefunction2/blob/40d92fba28b357f9f07cd097821abedbd10e6f29/src/CustomImageDataset.py))